# assigning and reusing variables in Rails - design pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been using the same pattern for returning json code (see example below). I'm getting a collection of photos and storing it in the variable. If tag param is present, I'm getting a more specific collection and reassigning it to the same variable. Then returning it as json. What would be a better design pattern to achieve the same thing?

```
photos = collection_of_photos
if params[:tag]
 photos = photos.find_all {|photo| some condition}
end
render json: photos
```

Comment: what kind of conditions could it be? Maybe a scope could be a nice solution?

Comment: I should have specified that collection_of_photos is an array of hashes. The condition is to select photos with the matching tag. The answer that @faraz provided solves the problem. I'll definitely look into scopes for future use when dealing with ActiveRecord objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the photos are ActiveRecord objects you should use a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to generate the appropriate query for the exact data you need. Otherwise, Rails will load all of the photos instead of the subset you need. Assuming your photos records have a single tag attribute, you can do something like the following:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  scope :with_tag, (tag) -> { where(tag: tag) }
end
```

In your controller you'd only need the call that scope since ActiveRecord scopes return an `#all` scope if no parameters are provided:

```
render json: Photo.with_tag(params[:tag])

# Equivalent when params[:tag] is nil
render json: Photo.all
```

Now say you're not dealing with ActiveRecord objects. Say you have an array of hashes:

```
photos = [{ name: '1.jpg', tag: 'flower'}, ... ]
```

You can create a helper method to perform the filtering:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    photos = [{ name: '1.jpg', tag: 'flower'}, ... ]
    render json: select_photos_by_tag(photos, params[:tag])
  end

  private

  def select_photos_by_tag(photos, tag)
    if tag
      photos.select { |photo| photo[:tag] == tag }
    else
      photos
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this is very helpful! I'm dealing with array of hashes, so the second answer was right on point. Thank you for explaining both situations!